# if with -ne and -or operators not working in powershell

Tags: powershell

The following if statements with -ne and -or operators is not working (Note I did not include the braces). $MyVariable is an integer coming in from a parameter in a function and having the if statement check the value. What I want is if **$MyVariable** is not equal to 16, 24 or 32 then return with error message otherwise continue. Calling the function as **FunctionName 16;** in the ps1 script.

Function is defined as follows:

```
function FunctionName
{
  param([Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
            [AllowNull()]
            [int]   $MyVariable,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
            [bool] $MyVariable2,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
            [bool] $MyVariable3);
  if (...
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the following if statements?

```
if ($MyVariable -ne 16 -or $MyVariable -ne 24 -or $MyVariable -ne 32)...
if (16 -ne $MyVariable -or 24 -ne $MyVariable -or 32 -ne $MyVariable)...
if (($MyVariable -ne 16) -or ($MyVariable -ne 24) -or ($MyVariable -ne 32))...
```

Comment: Logic flaw. *At least two* of the `-ne` comparisons will always be true. Use `-and` instead, or `-eq` for the comparison

Comment: Yes. After re-looking at the logic it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any one of the three equality comparisons return `$false`, the two others *must* return true (if `$x` equals 16 it will never equal 24 or 32), and so the statement will *always* evaluate to `$true`.

Change `-or` to `-and` to test for all 3 cases:

```
if ($MyVariable -ne 16 -and $MyVariable -ne 24 -and $MyVariable -ne 32){}
```

or check whether it *is* equal rather than not:

```
if ($MyVariable -eq 16 -or $MyVariable -eq 24 -or $MyVariable -eq 32){}
```

or, use the `-contains` operator instead:

```
if (@(16,24,32) -contains $MyVariable){}
```